# What causes blue screen of death?

Tags: windows, bsod

What are the causes of a blue screen of death?

Comment: [a screensaver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897558.aspx) can

Comment: Well, it depends, have you read the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death), there explain what generally causes and the BSOD shows something like this `STOP: 0x#### (0x####, 0x####, 0x####, 0x####) Error Name` if you google the error you can know what does cause the screen

Comment: The OS detected a non recoverable problem: a bug in the kernel or a hardware fault. It the past if was caused mainly by bugs in the kernel, now it is probably bugs in device drivers, and sometimes hardware faults. In my experience it has always been device drivers, and kernel bugs. (So you have to write a letter to the device manufacturer, or operating system writer, as no one else has the freedom to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the BSOD is caused by faulty hardware (most of the time, from experience) or a bad device driver.

If you read the BSOD it will usually give you the name of the device driver that triggered it and other debug information in the `STOP` line.

Microsoft provides a list of such codes: [Bug Check Code Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A BSOD can be caused by a variety of things, from faulty hardware, to driver problems such as ones that could be caused from a system update, to software you install that loads improperly which could cause damage to your system, it more or less is your computers way of keeping itself from being damaged any further than it may already be and alerting you to what the problem is or giving you a idea of what the problem is.